# Boolean and If statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, boolean

I have a code that converts an array of cells into strings across a loop. It correctly puts trues in the boolean found variables if the cell contains the specific string, but the if statements that are targeted with those variables true are skipped and only the very last else statement is preformed. I am not sure why this would be and would love any input as to why the if statement might not be seeing the variable as true. Thanks in advance.

```
trimmedValX = Trim$(ur(r, m(6)))  *creates the string
      Found1 = InStr(trimmedValX, "still sold")      *checks to see if string is in the created string, if it is variable is set as True
      Found2 = InStr(trimmedValX, "Still sold")
      Found3 = InStr(trimmedValX, "Discontinued")
If Found3 = True Then
   cell1.Interior.Color = rColor
ElseIf Found1 = True or Found2 = True Then
   cell1.Interior.Color = gColor
Else
   cell1.Interior.Color = mColor
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something whithout InStr at all

```
    trimmedValX = Trim$(ur(r, m(6)))

    With cell1.Interior
        If UCase(trimmedValX) Like "*DISCONTINUED*" Then
           .Color = rColor
        ElseIf UCase(trimmedValX) Like "*STILL SOLD*" Then
           .Color = gColor
        Else
           .Color = mColor
        End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 2):

`InStr` doesn't return a boolean value but instead returns the starting position of the substring. Try using this instead. [InStr Reference](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php)

```
trimmedValX = Trim$(ur(r, m(6)))  *creates the string
      Found1 = InStr(trimmedValX, "still sold")      *checks to see if string is in the created string, if it is variable is set as True
      Found2 = InStr(trimmedValX, "Still sold")
      Found3 = InStr(trimmedValX, "Discontinued")
If Found3 > 0 Then
   cell1.Interior.Color = rColor
ElseIf Found1 > 0 or Found2 > 0Then
   cell1.Interior.Color = gColor
Else
   cell1.Interior.Color = mColor
End If
```